# Find record length independent of EOL characters

Tags: shell, awk, eol

I am using awk to find the length of record .

```
awk '{print  length($0),$0}'
```

It works for Unix line endings `<LF>` but considers DOS line endings `<CR><LF>` as a character

Is there a way over this.

Comment: "It works for Unix line endings `<LF>`" - correct. "but considers DOS line endings `<CR><LF>` as a character" - no, it considers `<CR>` a character just like any other character, that's all.  There's no way to tell given input of `foo<CR><LF>` if that's `foo` followed by a DOS line ending of `<CR><LF>` or `foo<CR>` followed by a UNIX line ending of just `<LF>`. You need to really think about what your goal is of a script that tries to figure out the intent of the input it's reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Record Separator in `awk` to DOS line endings (`\r\n`), so that they are not treated as part of line. In Unix world, the usual endings in just `\n` which happens to be the default `RS` value.

```
awk -v RS="\r\n" '{ print  length($0), $0 }'
```

You could also `sub()`/`gsub()` functions to substitute those characters at the each line and apply your actions.

To handle both Unix/DOS style endings, make the RS definition a regex to occur zero or more occurrence of `\r`

```
awk -v RS="[\r]*\n" '{ print  length($0), $0 }'
```

Both the variants are supported in GNU `awk` only as POSIX version does not "accept" a multi-character record separator.

Comment: Thanks @Inian . But that code is not working for the files with \n . I receive both type of files and want to find length irrespective of the EOL

Comment: Thanks . This worked     ` awk -v RS="\r*\n" '{ print  length($0), $0 }' `

Comment: @kvantour: I did mean it for both, but now made it explicit. Thanks

Comment: ITYM `RS='\r?\n'` so you don't remove `\r`s before the DOS line ending `\r\n` but this is all kinda fragile since there's no way to tell given input of `foo\r\n` if that's `foo` followed by a DOS line ending or `foo\r` followed by a UNIX line ending.